# Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol atexit (linux/C)

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I get the error `Symbol lookup error: undefined symbol atexit (linux/C)` when I try to run my program. `atexit()` should be defined in `<stdlib.h>.`

Is there anything I could add to the `-l` option when I compile it with gcc? Or anything else I could do? This is in C.

I am trying to write a shared object where I call `atexit` once. I also define the corresponding function [like explained](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit).

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=mymal.so /bin/ls 
/bin/ls: symbol lookup error: ./mymal.so: undefined symbol: atexit
```

I don't get a error after compilation, just when I try to execute it.

I build the shared library with the commands ([source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-shobj/)):

```
gcc -fPIC -c -ldl mymal.c
ld -shared -soname mymal.so.1 -o mymal.so -lc mymal.o
```

solved: it worked with `g++` instead of `gcc`.

Comment: can you paste the code and error message?

Comment: /bin/ls: symbol lookup error: ./mymal.so: undefined symbol: atexit

Comment: @Bry: Please edit your original question with that error message. Also, **is this C++ or C**?

Comment: the code is really complicated and i am sure it wouldn't help here. I just call atexit and define the corresponding function. I included all necessarz libraries but somehow the symbol atexit cannot be found. but there is not error when i compile it, just when i try to execute it

Comment: @bry: Run ldd program_name to check if all required libraries are found.

Comment: Your issue is not with `atexit`, but with the function passed to it. Try a static version.

Comment: what's your glibc version ? And what command(s) did you use to build the shared library ?

Comment: @pmg: the function really was not static, but after trying it, it still doesn't work. Why do you think I should use a static function?

Comment: @Sander:  /lib32/libc.so.6 ----         
GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-0ubuntu13) stable release version 2.13, by Roland McGrath et al.

Comment: I meant static as not shared, not the C `static` keyword. I see your system accepts `atexit` within shared library (glibc >= 2.2.3) though. I'm stumped :(

Comment: solved: it worked with g++ instead of gcc

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `atexit`, not `Atexit`.